# Added aditional part of url after search form

Tags: javascript, html

I found form for search button overhere but I need added in url aditional text after search form input.
For example url is [www.111.com/search/static/](http://www.111.com/search/static/)

We need to replase "search" from form text below & added /static/ part in url after

```
<form onsubmit="window.location = 'https://111.com/' + search.value; return false;">

<input id="search" placeholder="Search" type="search" name="search"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

I need replase "search" for text inputed in form

For example we put in form "12345" our url  must be  https://111.com/12345/static

if we put 5678 it will be  https://111.com/5678/static

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answer edited after clarification from vasya vasya.)

If I got it right this time, you have a "template" URL like `https://111.com/search/static/`. And you want the term `search` to be replaced by the actual search string, like the example in your comment.

To do so, you would use:

```html
<form onsubmit="window.location = 'https://111.com/' + document.getElementById('search').value + '/static'; return false;">
```

The `getElementById` accesses the `input` element via its `id` attribute and then the `value` function returns the text entered.

Comment: I need replase "search" for text inputed in form 

For example we put in form "12345" & our url  must be  https://111.com/12345/static

if we put 5678
it will be  https://111.com/5678/static

Comment: Great! :) Then please be so kind and "accept" my answer and give it an upvote, if you like. :)